# PySerial timeout and callback

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have this short snippet of code here that works fine, but I have problem of getting rid of the hardcoded part.

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 38400 
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
ser.timeout = 1

ser.open()
ser.flushInput()
ser.write(command) #command here is a simple request for data to my device 
msg = ser.read(200)
ser.close()
```

While this works fine, the problem I'm having is this. The length of the returned message can vary from 8 byte to almost 200 bytes depending on what was registered. By using a timeout, I prevent my read command from stalling if it doesn't receive 200 bytes. I also don't know ahead the length of the returned message I therefore can't change dynamically the ser.read. Also, there is no constant endline or constant character at the end of the transmission to lock on in a while loop.

Is there a more stable/dynamic way to do this? I could run out of time if the request is too long or I could bust my read buffer without having the complete data transmission. On the other end, increasing the timer mean that my request rate will be slowed down (there is no problem in increasing the read buffer however).

Comment: Will the device that is sending the responses send the reply in one go, or will there be gaps in time in the data? Really, a device sending data over a serial link should provide some sort of packetisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reply had a header containing a length field, you could do a fixed-size `read()` to get the header, then a variable `read()` to get the rest...

If there is truly no way to tell how big the reply is, then a timeout is the only conceivable solution.  However, you have apparently missed the detail that PySerial has two different timeout values: one that applies to the overall operation, and one that applies to gaps between characters.  You could set `timeout` to multiple seconds, so that you never prematurely end a valid reply, and set `inter_byte_timeout` (was `interCharTimeout` in older versions) to perhaps 0.1 second, so that your `read()` will end almost immediately once the device stops sending data.  (This assumes that the device never inserts pauses in the middle of sending a reply.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the inter_byte _timeout value. I could set the timout to 3 seconds and the inter_byte to 0.1. The device never pauses during a reply. 

the fixed-size read could work as well. But, there is variable length within the variable length therefore it gets a bit weird to code!

Answer (score 0):

If the responses (from 8 bytes to 200 bytes) are contiguous, then you could have a loop which concatenates bytes received from calls to `ser.read(200)`, but having set the timeout to something like 1/100th second. Then when you have two timeouts in succession where no bytes were received, then you know you are at the end of the message.

```
exit = 0
while exit < 2:
    more = ser.read(200)
    msg += more
    if len(more) == 0:
        exit += 1
    else:
        exit = 0
```

Comment: while this solution is workable. I liked the elegance of the solution proposed by jasonharper.